# How can I ensure iCloud is completely disabled and stays disabled?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 7, running iOS 11.2.6.

I had earlier disabled iCloud but it recently got activated as some kind of a side-effect of some other activity (maybe my Apple ID email change, an iOS update, or something else).

What steps can take to ensure that iCloud is completely disabled and stays disabled?

Comment: What did you do to disable iCloud?